# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}2^{2n}(\frac{i}{2})^{2n}}{2n}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Question 4 of section 11.7 of Calculus by Tom Apostol asks us to find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}2^{2n}z^{2n}}{2n}$. Using the alternating series test, the series converges when $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|2z|^{2n}}{2n} = 0$, or $|z| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ (a solution is posted here: https://www.stumblingrobot.com/2016/03/31/determine-radius-convergence-1n22nz2n-2n/). However, some commentors claimed the series diverges for $z = \frac{i}{2}$, which I haven't been able to understand, since it seems like that would converge by the alternating series test. If someone could explain to me what I'm missing, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At $z=\dfrac i2$ the series is no longer alternating. The numerator reduces to $1$,

$$(-1)^n 2^{2n} \left(\frac i2\right)^{2n} = (-1)^n (i^2)^n = (-1)^{2n} = 1$$

and the resulting harmonic series diverges.

Comment: Got it, thank you! New question: Would we not be able to apply the alternating series test on any other complex numbers (ie $\frac{1}{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$), since the $a_n$'s wouldnt be monotonic decreasing?

Comment: If we can't use the alternating series test, could we use Dirichlet's test along with the fact that $2^{2n}z^{2n}$ is bounded when it isn't equal to 1?

Comment: Also, thinking about it a little more I'm not even sure how you'd define a monotonically decreasing sequence when complex numbers are involved - does the alternating series test just not work when $a_n$ is complex (or am I missing something again)?

Comment: To apply the AST for convergence, you need to show $|a_n|$ is decreasing, not $a_n$. The latter would get you nowhere since complex numbers are not ordered.

Comment: What about, say,  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}(-1)^{n}}{n}$? Letting $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, with your definition of AST this series would converge. But we know it doesn't since it equals the harmonic series.

Comment: Typically "alternating series" refers to one of the form $\sum\limits_n (-1)^n a_n$ with the understanding that $a_n$ is free of any extra factors of $(-1)^n$. Clearly letting $a_n=(-1)^n b_n$ produces a non-alternating series $\sum\limits_n b_n$.